# windows services recovery not working

Tags: java, windows-services

I've set up my Java based service to "Restart the Service" for the 1st, 2nd and subsequent failures.  I've set the reset fail count to 1 day and the restart time to 1 minute.  I can see the termination of my service in the event viewer but I never see any attempt at a restart.

I'm not sure why this is happening.  I trigger the shutdown by calling System.exit(-1) when we determine a third party app we use isn't responding.  To test this I call System.exit(-1) in a place I can easily trigger.  However, our service never restarts during testing and when our users hit the real error.

I have no idea why it wouldn't trigger.  Is the Java Sytsem.exit(-1) determined to be a "graceful" exit condition?  If so, how can I trigger a restart from Java?

Thanks,
-Mike

Comment: Have you tried terminating the application by throwing an exception from Java?

Comment: Throwing an exception is not triggering a restart.

Answer (score 0):

run a command dos : "taskkill /f /im XXX.exe" where XXX is the name of your service